# 2.2 Faster way to regenerate css in developer mode

Tags: css, magento2.2, static-content, less-css

In developer mode, static files are mostly symlinked so making changes is immediately visible in frontend. However, when making changes to CSS this is not the case.

The minimal files I have to delete are **var/view_preprocessed/.../css** and **pub/static/frontend/.../css**.

However, it is still a bit slow and inconvenient. Is there a way to activate some sort of file watcher that will automatically regenerate the things it needs to?
(Something like compass in 1.9.X RWD theme.)